# Prompting for five test scores and printing the average

Tags: java, beginner, console

I am not sure how to properly make this readable. I have been trying to find examples online but I cannot find any that are specific to this simple program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class KifahUnit3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String first;  //first name
        String last;  //last name
        String full;  //full name
        Boolean nameMatch = false;
        int score1;
        int score2;
        int score3;
        int score4;
        int score5;
        int totalScore;
        int x;
        double scoreAverage;
        System.out.print("Please enter your first name: ");
        first = stdIn.next();
        System.out.print("Please enter your last name: ");
        last = stdIn.next();
        System.out.println(first + " " + last);
        nameMatch = first.equals(last);
        if (nameMatch == true) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Hello, " + first + " " + last + " "
                    + "your first and last name are the same.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "Hello, " + first + " " + last + " "
                    + "your first and last name are different.");
            full = first + last;
            System.out.println("The length of your first name is: " + first.length());
            System.out.println("The length of your full name is: " + full.length());
            System.out.println("Your initials are " + first.charAt(0) + last.charAt(0));

            System.out.println("Please enter your test scores");
            System.out.print("Score 1= ");
            score1 = stdIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Score 2= ");
            score2 = stdIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Score 3= ");
            score3 = stdIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Score 4= ");
            score4 = stdIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Score 5= ");
            score5 = stdIn.nextInt();
            scoreAverage = (score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5) / 5;
            System.out.println(
                    "Score 1= " + score1 + "; " + "Score 2= " + score2 + "; " + "Score 3= "
                    + score3 + ";  " + "Score 4= " + score4 + "; " + "Score 5= " + score5);
            totalScore = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5;
            x = 10;
            System.out.println("Total= " + totalScore);
            System.out.println("Average: " + (scoreAverage + x));
            System.out.println("Ooops! Made a mistake. Your average is:  " + scoreAverage);

        }
    } // end main
} // end class KifahUnit3
```

Comment: (giving it a shot) Welcome to CR! Are you on Java 8?

Comment: No, I am using Java SE 7

Comment: Why are you adding 10 to the average before printing it?

Comment: Why does the first name being the same as the last name trigger a special case? "Mohammed Mohammed" is a rather common name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Firstly - Java Code Convention**

Read the Java code convention, see this [cheatsheet](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/internal/courses/java/msc/resources/code-conventions.html)

The [Java Code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html) has a more detailed description -

Why use code conventions (From the link) -

> Code conventions are important to programmers for a number of reasons:
>
> - 80% of the lifetime cost of a piece of software goes to maintenance.
> - Hardly any software is maintained for its whole life by the original
>   author.
> - Code conventions improve the readability of the software,
>   allowing engineers to understand new code more quickly and thoroughly.

---

**Secondly - Refactoring**

Start by using arrays - this will really reduce the amount of code you wrote. For example:

```
// Declare this constant at the top of the class 
private static final int NUMBER_OF_SCORES = 5;

int[] score = new int[NUMBER_OF_SCORES];

System.out.println("Please enter your test scores");

// Read all Scores
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
  score[i] = stdIn.nextInt();
}
```

With arrays, you can also easily calculate the total score and output each score -

```
// Total Score
int totalScore = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
  totalScore += score[i];
}

// Output All the scores
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
  System.out.print("score " + i + " = " + score[i]);
}
```

You can also introduce a Person class - example. (Take note of the getInitials function)

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String surname;

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getInitials() {
        return "" + name.charAt(0) + surname.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

With the introduction of a Person class, the main function can transform into the for example. (Also splitting up the main function into smaller parts)

```
public static final int NUMBER_OF_SCORES = 5;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter your first name: ");
    // Read First Name
    String firstName = stdIn.next();
    System.out.print("Please enter your last name: ");
    // Read Last Name
    String lastName = stdIn.next();
    System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    if (firstName.equals(lastName)) {
        System.out.println("Your first and last name are the same.");
    } else {
        // Now you know you have a valid person.
        Person person = new Person(firstName, lastName);
        System.out.println("Your first and last name are different.");
        processName(person);
        readAndProcessScores();
    }
}

private static void processName(Person person) {
    String full = person.getName() + person.getSurname();
    System.out.println("The length of your first name is: " + person.getName().length());
    System.out.println("The length of your full name is: " + full.length());
    System.out.println("Your initials are " + person.getInitials());
}

public static void readAndProcessScores() {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] score = new int[NUMBER_OF_SCORES];
    System.out.println("Please enter your test scores");
    // Read all Scores
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
        System.out.print("Score " + i + " = ");
        score[i] = stdIn.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Output All the scores
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
        System.out.print("score " + i + " = " +score[i] + " ");
    }

    // Total Score
    int totalScore = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SCORES; i++) {
        totalScore += score[i];
    }

    double scoreAverage = (((double) totalScore) / NUMBER_OF_SCORES);
    System.out.println("Total = " + totalScore);
    System.out.println("Your average is:  " + scoreAverage);
}
```

**This code itself can be refactored even more, but this I leave to you :)**
Try doing the following -

- Introduce one more class.
- Extract the calculate total score into its own function. Use this declaration:

  ```
    public static double calculateAverage(int[] scores)
  ```
- Add some comments to the methods :)

---

**General tips**

- Always use good descriptive variable names.
- Declare variables as needed (Close to where they are used).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow! That was extremely helpful. You made the code so much more cleaner and understandable. I really appreciate it. I hope to have your skills one day =]

Comment: @Reg I've [some suggestions](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103963/27975) built upon your answer...

Comment: Are You sure your person class needs all those getters and setters?

Comment: No, you are right. Will update.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon [@Reg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103948/27975)'s answer...

1. **Avoid `new String()`.**

   Since strings are immutable in Java, there's *almost* never a need to do a `new String()` unless you're using one the many array-based constructors. This would have given you a `String` too:

   ```
   String initials = "" + name.charAt(0) + surname.charAt(0);
   ```

   Or if you also want to eliminate relying on the `""` entirely:

   ```
   String initials = name.substring(0, 1) + surname.substring(0, 1);
   ```
2. **Validation.**

   I'm not sure why you think a valid name is [one with a different name from surname](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), but leaving that strange requirement aside, you can also consider introducing either a validation method, or let the the `Person` class determine that for you. The latter is slightly more preferred, as the class should know what is a valid requirement and *[encapsulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_programming%29)* that.

   ```
   // validation method suggestion
   private static boolean isValidPersonNames(String firstname, String surname) {
       return !firstname.equals(surname);
   }

   // inside the Person class
   private static Person createFromInput(Scanner scanner) {
       String firstname = scanner.nextLine();
       String surname = scanner.nextLine();
       return !firstname.equals(surname) ? new Person(firstname, surname) : null;
   }
   ```

   For example, if you opted for the Person-class suggestion, you wouldn't have a large-ish `if-else` code-block, and even better, you can keep prompting the user until you get a usable `Person` object:

   ```
   public static void main() {
       ...
       Person person;
       // stdIn is a Scanner instance
       while ((person = Person.createFromInput(stdIn)) == null) {
           System.out.println("Not a valid person's name, please try again.");
       }
       // person will be non-null from here on
       processName(person); // or printName()?
       readAndProcessScores();
   }
   ```
3. **Read carefully.**

   [@Reg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103948/27975)'s answer suggested the following method:

   ```
   public static void readAndProcessScores() {
       Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
       ...
   }
   ```

   This is *slightly* troublesome for three reasons:

   1. It is not evident what this method is *reading from*.
   2. Since we already have a `Scanner` instance reading from `System.in` from the `main()` method, we can reuse the same instance. *That* should then be used for the method's argument.
   3. If `System.in` is closed by accident from another place, such as doing a `scanner.close()`, where `scanner` is also wrapping `System.in`, reading console input in this method will fail.

   There <s>is</s> [was](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/103948/2) also one **bug** towards the end of this method, when calculating the average...

   ```
   int NUMBER_OF_SCORES = 5;
   int totalScore = /* <calculated> */;
   double scoreAverage;
   scoreAverage = totalScore / NUMBER_OF_SCORES;
   System.out.println("Your average is:  " + scoreAverage);
   ```

   Creating the temporary variable `scoreAverage` (and doing the assignment on the next line...) is just one minor thing to improve on:

   ```
   System.out.println("Your average is:  " + (totalScore / NUMBER_OF_SCORES));
   ```

   The **bug** is that we are doing an integer-based division here, which *loses precision first* before the [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) takes place. To remedy this, we just need to convert any of the operand to the intended `double` primitive type first, before doing the calculation:

   ```
   System.out.println("Your average is:  " + (((double) totalScore) / NUMBER_OF_SCORES));
   ```

   Of course, declaring `totalScore` as a `double` in the first place will be the simpler solution still.
4. **`try-with-resources`.**

   Since you are already on Java 7, do consider wrapping your `Scanner` instance inside a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in order to accustom yourself to safe closing of resources.